# Implementing Python-like slice in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Python has by far the best slice implementation I've ever used. As a quick evening project I felt like trying to implement Python's slice construct in a JavaScript function (thinking about sending a pr to a certain library with Python's slice semantics). I came up with the code below, and I'm trying to improve my code. I would love feedback or alternative implementations.

I think I hit all the edge cases, but I only briefly skimmed [the Python source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8039a20b18cc/Objects/sliceobject.c), so I could easily be wrong.

```
/**
 * Implementation of Python's `slice` function... Get a cloned subsequence
 * of an iterable (collection with length property and array like indexs).
 * Will handle both strings and array(likes).
 * 
 * @param {Array|String} collection
 * @param {None|Integer} start First index to include. If negative it will be indicies from end
                             (i.e. -1 is last item). Omit or pass 0/null/undefined for 0.
 * @param {None|Integer} end Last index to include. If negative it will be indicies from end
                             (i.e. -1 is last item). Omit or pass null/undefined for end.
 * @param {None|Intger} step Increments to increase by (non-1 will skip indicies). Negative values
                              will reverse the output.
 * @returns {Array|String} sliced array
 *
 * @example
 * var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 * slice(list) // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 * slice(list, 2) // => [3, 4, 5]
 * slice(list, 2, 4) // => [3, 4]
 * slice(list, -2) // => [4, 5]
 * slice(list, null, -1) // => [1, 2, 3, 4]
 * slice(list, null, null, 2) // => [1, 3, 5]
 * slice(list, null, null, -2) // => [5, 3, 1]
 * slice("kids a devil I tell ya", 7, -10, -1) // => "lived"
 */
function slice(collection, start, end, step) {
    var length = collection.length,
        isString = typeof collection == "string", // IE<9 have issues with accessing strings by indicies ("str"[0] === undefined)
        result = [];
    if (isString) {
        collection = collection.split("");
    }
    if (start == null) {
        start = 0;
    } else if (start < 0) {
        start = length + start;
    }
    if (end == null || end > length) {
        end = length;
    } else if (end < 0) {
        end = length + end;
    }
    if (step == null) {
        step = 1;
    } else if (step === 0) {
        throw "Slice step cannot be zero";
    }
    if (step > 0) {
        for (; start < end; start += step) {
            result.push(collection[start]);
        }
    } else {
        for (end -= 1; start <= end; end += step) {
            result.push(collection[end]);
        }
    }
    // Return a string for input strings otherwise an array
    return isString ? result.join("") : result;
}
```

Comment: I had an answer here, but I think it can be reduced to a comment: 1) throw errors and not strings, and 2) that `start == null` might confuse people. It confused me (and I'm not normally one of the "always use ===" pundits either).

Comment: Welcome to javascript. You can put your example into [jasmine](jasmine.github.io) as tests.

Comment: for readability i would personally go for if ( is_null(param) ) but appart from that. I like what you did there

Comment: @dagg I liked your answer. Esp handling steps

Comment: Particularly it made me reconsider using `push` instead of precomputing the length: `length = Math.ceil(Math.max(end - start, 0) / Math.abs(step)), result = Array(length);` The I can iterate like you!

Comment: @megawac but it made be sad that I forgot so much stuff I used to know, like the exact extent of IE8's crappyness, or how weird type coercion actually is. So I deleted it in shame.

Comment: If it doesn't pain you too much I'd like to add your code to a benchmark :). Your code helped me spot some oversights in my own so I think it was definitely a good answer for this site

Comment: @megawac go for it :) I remember thinking yours might actually be faster, because mine had to test two conditions in the step loop to make sure step was in bounds.

Comment: @megawac if speed is one of your primary concerns, there are some things you could do that I think would speed up common cases. If `collection` has a `slice` property, and `step` is not provided (or 1), you can just return `collection.slice(start, end)` early. Also if step is -1, if `collection` is an array you can do the above and then call `collection.reverse()`, or if it's a string, convert to an array, reverse it, join it, and return. Would add some code bloat, but should run faster for those common cases. I'm assuming people don't usually use `step`, but if they do, it's usually -1.

Comment: Performance isn't the primary concern (tho always nice), its more handling all the edge cases correctly. I can't call `reverse` as it will reverse in place (and too edge casey anyway). Anyway, even for the simplest case (http://jsperf.com/cr-52768) this implementation seems faster surprisingly

Answer (score 3):

## Throwing errors

You should only throw errors, not strings.

```
throw new Error("Slice step cannot be zero");
```

## Leveraging existing API

What you're doing looks very similar to the existing `slice` except for the last parameter, `step`. This could be more compact if you used built-in `slice` for everything and then apply the step afterward.

```
function slice(collection, start, end, step) {
    var slice = collection.slice || Array.prototype.slice,
        sliced = slice.call(collection, start, end),
        result, length, i;

    if (!step) {
        return sliced;
    }
    result = [];
    length = sliced.length;
    i = (step > 0) ? 0 : length - 1;
    for (; i < length && i >= 0; i += step) {
        result.push(sliced[i]);
    }
    return typeof collection == "string" ? result.join("") : result;
}
```

This would require you to pass `undefined` in the places you have `null` in your usage examples. If you want to be able to pass `null`, you can add `if (start === null) start = undefined`, and the same for `end`.

Comment: `start == null` only returns true for `undefined` and `null` which I think ~~ the Python `NoneType` struct, whereas `!start` returns true for `NaN`, `0`, etc. Good point on the `Error`. I was trying to avoid calling the native slice for cross environment concerns (ie nodelists)

Comment: @megawac What's the problem with calling slice on nodelists? Something like `[].slice.apply(document.scripts)` should work fine everywhere shouldn't it?

Comment: [Throws an error on IE<=8](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3199627/1517919) IIRC. Still points for nice alternative!

Comment: Ugh, [you're right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). And I actually commented on that SO thread you linked years ago, so I must have read it. How quickly we forget...

Comment: I'd love to forget that bug as well, Dagg Nabbit! :)

Comment: Thanks Dagg, your step iteration helped point me to a better algorithm http://jsperf.com/cr-52768

Comment: Just some nits, you don't handle slice for the case `slice("smt", 1, 2)` as its an array.

Comment: @megawac there was no need to, since `collection.slice` was `String.prototype.slice` in that case, if I'm understanding you correctly. That basically worked as an alias for `"smt".slice(1, 2)`. Take another look at your perf; in daggTest you test if `sliced` is a string and if so, try to call `sliced.join`...

Comment: True, good catch.

Comment: I believe it would make more sense to throw a `RangeError` instead of a normal `Error`, although both are preferential to throwing a string.